# Jquery ajax, data with src of an image

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a query in ajax like that :

```
    var gif = $('.generated-img').attr('src').replace('data:image/gif;base64,', '');
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url: "/webcam/",
        data: {image_gif:gif, test:'ok'},
        success: function () {
            console.log('ok');
        }
    });
```

So, i retrieve the src attribut of my image, i remove the header, and i need to send this data with ajax to my script `/webcam/`.

With this code, when i check my `$_POST` datas in my php script, i haven't the variable image_gif. When i check in firebug, i just have the variable test, but not image_gif..

Any ideas ? If i check my variable gif juste before the ajax query, it's ok...

Edit : Output :

> image_gif=R0lGODlhQAHwAPcAAAAAACEWEhcUFBITFBEVFRQXGhQXGxYZHRYYHBocHR4fIBcgIRcgJRYdKRkgKxkhMBUoMhUmNhclNxskNx0lNSAnMyUpLygoKScpJi0qJzAtKjUvLD0xKzs0Lj44MTw6NTs4ODk3OTc4OjQ1OTI5Oi43PCwzOCc1OyQzOiAwPxkrRBcrRxgrTRwsSx00TiU7Sic%2BTSs%2BUjBBVzhEVzxCTUFCRURAQUs%2BP01BPE8%2FPkxDQklJSklITElLTFFQUVdRUFlTU19UUGRVTWhQRWxNSHBTTXVVTX1aTIJeS4tZSZdTSaxWT8ddW9JmYs1xZsB5Za9%2FZqZ%2FaaF9ZZx5YZR0XY9xXotvX4t1aYl5c4d6doN7d354cXh2cXV1cW91d2t0eGpxdG1qaG1mZGlkZl1eY01ZY0tXakhYdFBlg1Foi0xplz1rsytt2iRu7R5w9x9u8h9q5B5lyR5lnx1lgR9lciBlaSBlZyBjXyJhWSNlWyZrXCdpXiduXih0Yyx4aih5bSmAcSqCdiqDdS6GdzCIeyuLfy2OgjCOgjKSijKYjjKXkzaclTqenEGboEaQn06GpFOBp1mAq2CApmmDpG6EoXKIo3iKoH%2BOoYSLmYmKlZCNkZONjpKNiZGMgpOHfpaKf6CMf6aOgqqTg6qVgq6WhLSYg72ag8GhhMapi8Sokr%2Bol7qmmLejmLKflrCdlKuclqKbmZyZnqCenqalo6mmpK2npbGlpbWno7imo8CmosmnodShoNuhoNajosqvpsSyrMOysMGwsb6wsLuxsLiwsbWwsrOytq20vKOxwaS1yKK50aW80K%2FAzLbAxbvEwcLHw8DEvsW%2Fvcq%2FvM%2FAutPBuNjEt9%2FBt9rJvdvPw9fRydPQztjS0djU1NnX1tXX187W28LU4rrX6LTb8bXg97zl%2Bsbu%2B8r0%2FNLr8dnl6drk5dzi4t3e3eLd2uPc3uff4%2Bzg5uvk6O7q5%2Bzu6uzx7Oz19en5%2Ben8%2FP39%2Ff39%2Fv39%2Ff78%2Bv778f78%2Bf38%2Fv78%2Ff78%2FiH%2FC05FVFNDQVBFMi4wAwEAAAAh%2BQQADgAAACwAAAAAQAHwAAAI%2FgDxCRwo0J7BevQS0ps3byG9egPRoUuXTh1FihMlpkNHbyC%2FdN68fdP2rKTJkyidQUP5DBo0Z8NiRjOJTVs2bdu2adMW0lu3nz%2FXeVtHtKg3eASTKl2qNN8%2BdrH25WNK8F88a%2B%2BoMu1HTx00LT2AhBGjRUsXIEDI1OixY0eNt29p0KgBwkYNEhgU6E3Ad28CvXovVAD89%2B9ewBgsKC5BorFjEx%2F%2BQBQ7EjkbfcyDCzoAAie%2BMoYljqGDXIWLXDyDaDR30YsMaLcFetVWGmngAx56N3wjk2%2BhnXdFFjheYv7N12f5%2BZ7fM2P5SMBG8AW4MeSWSwnK4IVZoOMZs6iHxVEoHw5HTH5zg4dGJCwQfujPkI8lzkYIco%2BUr9yRMe%2BsiFdSyZmvRJNzgkoseO6dWktjDDbw0MJ38AMapDJi8JhGNiSlQnwU4xXyEUgJ88F1quiDHx6DhQ9E%2FiCLb2iiVMJrojU3RK1xZq%2Ffdn6rvI22IheBVb6C9%2Ft5WUSjvDMerwM%2FPLWKRLUa5OivorE1s8I1csEtXOMDl3AMs8AMhjUQ%2BpBTUOc5fbQQDDE38hAP69AOFSMcqbdQqPdQ%2FyMS9iJJnVWCaFKCwzQTuMc4tKAFPJcTHUUUTTcKvoAFNgAiGtBSmKB0tREP0tANDrgPwQAL8xApOrZK%2FFAx9LAJH%2BADzjALPYBVPCBmq2ID3UM14%2BQz6KdvXeQAb3UBUHMBKsJN2XNvYcRW9cUifDc1yBJo4hNoL6Jo%2F1cCZjY1VCMCEjIhImA5POAFz6AOYMIP8PALuLAN1Ucu%2FvpwGwmBEJomD44IJsG2AdfyJp60Id%2F0IewA0BhUoezMUDbUoduQCF6UMBocRHgOqApM4aZuosJrJu76QW90ZG8ExJZiIUhGQwNZAd3kDamSIYemIZOYCoUbC0VjIcnaIImMIUp4ASw%2BQd2cIJUcJAHYbNvYAu34AdayIEO%2BMEOEAJPEIVVGAZgeIXlkIVQKDUlhCsxiCJh0AZtcAbfewZtAL7gG4xuGD6%2B6MLAUr4EC8MZab5VaIVQOMOMEY5KeY3e%2FsANj4BDk%2Bi%2B%2FUAYE%

Comment: Remember JavaScript is function scoped so if the `gif` variable is overwritten later in the function, maybe in a loop, then it will be overwritten in the data object too.

Comment: It's a generated image, so in the src, i have the real src, and not the file path ;) And my variable gif is never used after that. I can name my variable "image_gif_bloblobloblo", it's the same, i can't retrieve this variable in my php script...

Comment: what is the output of `print_r($_POST);` ??

Comment: Are you sure `gif` not containing `null` or `undefined`?.

Comment: just before my $ajax, gif is not null. Print_r is : Array
(
    [test] => ok
)
true

Comment: paste the value of gif please

Comment: 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

Comment: something like that ^^

Comment: try this `data: {image_gif:encodeURIComponent(gif), test:'ok'},`

Comment: I have already tried this... no effec

Comment: and try this as well `data: {image_gif:'lorem', test:'ok'}` and check post again if you get `image_gif`

Comment: When you check on firebug what data are you sending to the server, is 'image_gif' sending? Have you tried 
`data: image_gif: $('.generated-img').attr('src').replace('data:image/gif;base64,', ''), test:'ok'` in your `$.ajax`?

Comment: With data: {image_gif:'lorem', test:'ok'} it's ok, i have image_gif ;) With data: image_gif: $('.generated-img').attr('src').replace('data:image/gif;base64,', ''), it's the same, i haven't image_gif

Comment: My data src is really big.. is that the problem ?

Comment: what is the max_post_size in you php?

Comment: and check the image size as well

Comment: I have 64Mo to post_max_size... And the image is just 6ko

Comment: Can you please show us the output of `console.log( $.param({image_gif:gif, test:'ok'}) )` ?

Comment: if you try to encode base64 image string, maybe this can help you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/246801/how-can-you-encode-a-string-to-base64-in-javascript ... If it's not help you, sorry :P my bad.

Comment: check my edit for the output, it's just a little part of the data

Comment: Is there a way the PHP script can pull the image instead of pushing it with jQuery?