# jQuery ajax, large data string (2M length)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have posted a topic just before for this problem [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21983434/jquery-ajax-data-with-src-of-an-image?noredirect=1#comment33314986_21983434) but now i can see the real problem, so i post a new topic.

I'm trying to post with `$.ajax` a very big data string. When i check `myString.length` i have approximately `2 000 000` of characters.

So, when i check in my php script, i don't have my `$_POST` variable.

How can i post this huge data ?

I have already check the php.ini, i have 64Mo to the post_max_size

Edit : When i test on my wamp server, it's ok. This code doesn't work on my server

Comment: Is it not possible to break the data into several chunks?

Comment: Hum, chunks of how many characters ? And if i can have an other solution, it's better ^^

Comment: Is your `php.ini` line well written: `post_max_size = 64M`? What server are you using? Some changes on `php.ini` require Apache (if used) to be restarted.

Answer (score 0):

I have break the data into several chunk for my problem :

```
gif = gif.match(/.{1,500000}/g);
```